# Use Replace Function in Case When Condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, postgresql-9.3

Table Name is `tabelea` columns are `name,expdate`. Both Column have not null contraints. Both column had character varying data type.

Values

```
name expdate

A     '10-05-2015'
B     '    '
```

Now i want to fetch the value which `expdate` is not empty then convert to date format otherwise so empty. So i tried like this

```
select name,case when replace(expdate,' ','') <> '' then
to_char(cast(expdate as date),'dd-MM-yyyy') else null end from tablea
```

But is not work its show error **invalid input syntax for type date: "' '"**.

How to solve this?

i tried `trim` also.

**Postgresql 9.3**

Comment: sorry sir typing mistake

Comment: How about if you check for length instead?

Comment: Use date data type for dates... Don't cheat and allow empty values for NOT NULL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine that in a single call if you convert empty strings to a `null` value:

```
select name,
       to_char(cast(nullif(trim(expdate), '') as date),'dd-MM-yyyy') 
from tablea;
```

The `cast` relies on some implicit data type conversion. It would be better to use `to_date()` with an explicit format instead:

```
to_char(to_date(nullif(trim(expdate), ''), 'dd-mm-yyyy'),'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a9831/1

Comment: @Sathish: works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a9831/1 there must be something you are not telling us.

Comment: if i change text to character varying (10) not display anything

Comment: @Sathish: `varchar(10)` does not make any difference http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/53dbf/1  Please create a SQLFiddle that shows your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tilde to compare your string with the desired date pattern, before making it a date:

```
select
  name,
  case when expdate ~ '^[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{4}$' then
    to_date(expdate, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
  else
    null
  end as the_date
from tablea;
```

(Of course it is a bad idea to use a string data type to store dates in the first place.)

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a66cf/2.